# Is there any way to run a Foreground service continuously in .NET MAUI (Android )?

Tags: android, xamarin.android, maui

I have a foreground service which gets the device's location every 5 seconds and sends it to a server. But every day or so, the location data will not get uploaded to the server even though the foreground service is still running. I'm running the get location service on a different thread.
Foreground Service StartCommandResult Method

```
public override StartCommandResult OnStartCommand(Intent intent, [GeneratedEnum] StartCommandFlags flags, int startId)
{
    switch (intent.Action)
    {
        case "START_SERVICE":
            Console.WriteLine("Start Service");
            Task.Run(() =>
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Task is running");
                try
                {
                    var locShare = new GetLocationService();
                    locShare.RunLocation(_cts.Token).Wait();
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(e);
                    throw;
                }
            }, _cts.Token);

            RegisterNotification(); //Proceed to notify
            break;

        case "STOP_SERVICE":
            _cts.Cancel();
            StopForeground(true);
            StopSelfResult(startId);
            _cts.Dispose();
            break;
    }
```

Get Location Service Class

```
public async Task RunLocation(CancellationToken token)
{
    await Task.Run(async () =>
    {
        if (token.IsCancellationRequested)
            stopping = true;
        while (!stopping)
        {
            token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
            try
            {
                await Task.Delay(5000, token);

                var request = new GeolocationRequest(GeolocationAccuracy.Medium, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));
                var location = await Geolocation.Default.GetLocationAsync(request, token);

                if (location != null)
                {
                    var gpsData = new GpsRecord()
                    {
                        Id = Guid.NewGuid(),
                        DateTime = location.Timestamp.DateTime,
                        GPSData = location.ToString(),
                        IsSync = 1,
                       
                    };

                    gpsRecordList.Add(gpsData);

                    if (InternetService.Internet)
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            var result = await data.PostRecordAsync(gpsRecordList);
                            Debug.WriteLine("result: " + result.StatusCode + " " + DateTime.Now.ToString("O"));
                        }
                        catch (Exception e)
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine(e);
                        }

                        if (_isOfflineSync)
                        {
                            try
                            {
                                var syncOfflineData = new SyncOfflineData();
                                await syncOfflineData.Start();
                                _isOfflineSync = false;
                            }
                            catch (Exception e)
                            {
                                Debug.WriteLine(e);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        _isOfflineSync = true;
                        try
                        {
                            gpsData.IsSync = 0;
                            var result = await DatabaseConnectionService.AddRecordAsync(gpsData);
                            Debug.WriteLine(result);
                            Debug.WriteLine("Added to local database");
                        }
                        catch (Exception e)
                        {
                            Debug.WriteLine(e);
                            throw;
                        }
                    }

                    gpsRecordList.Clear();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine(ex);
            }
        }
        return;
    }, token);
}
```

Comment: In my opinion, your solution is to update every 5 seconds using the while loop and Task.Delay(5000) really hard. 
you can use the Timer that can simulate running your callbackMethod which can try to get the location data every 5 seconds like: 
    Timer timer =  new Timer(getLocationData,"test",1000,5000); Example: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.timer?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=net-7.0

Comment: The foreground service might need a permission. You can check this link about [Foreground services](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/foreground-services#bg-access-restriction-exemptions) for further information.